# How to check whether a list<string> is containing any string value or not 

Tags: c#, string, list, .net-4.0, contains

The below code is list element.

```
List <string> lsLinks = new List<string>();
```

Before adding new strings i want to check whether list is containing the string i am going to add or not. How can i do that with most efficient way.

I can iterate through whole list and check but i think that would not be performance wise.

Comment: I don't get it, what is "list"?

Comment: The *simplest* way is to use the framework's [`List<T>.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) method, which is certainly better than iterating yourself. As for *most efficient*, well, if you need better performance than `Contains`, see Marc's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *most efficient* way would be to simply use a `HashSet<T>`, either *instead* of the list (if order doesn't matter), or *in addition* to the list, if it does.

i.e. either

```
HashSet<string> lsLinks = new HashSet<string>();
// now just Add() all you like; only ever one of each, but order is not defined
```

or

```
List<string> lsLinks = new List<string>();
HashSet<string> unique = new HashSet<string>();
// now, when needed, check if the item is new to "unique"
if(unique.Add(newValue)) lsLinks.Add(newValue);
```

You might also find a use for `.Distinct()` in LINQ, i.e.

```
var uniqueList = someSourse.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Didn't know about HashSet, that's great.

Comment: actually list size will be maximum lets say 200. should i still use hashset for such small numbers ? order is not important.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG at *large* numbers, the hash-set would definitely win; at *small* numbers, you need to profile if you want to know for sure - `O(n)` can be faster than `O(1)` for small `n` - meaning: the overhead (of all the hashing etc) can outweigh the benefit for small groups. Again, the emphasis: measure it.

Comment: thanks for answer. i am learning new thing with every question :D

Answer (score 6):

If you've *got* to have a `List<string>`, and you can't sort it first, then there's nothing you can do that will be faster than a simple `Contains` which walks the whole list. If the list is sorted, you could perform a binary search instead.

If you can use a `HashSet<string>` instead, that will obviously be a lot quicker as the set gets larger. (For small sets the performance difference is likely to be irrelevant.)

Note that a `HashSet<T>` does *not* preserve the order of the elements though - so if that's important to you, you may want to keep a `HashSet<string>` *and* a `List<string>`. Then you can do:

```
if (stringSet.Add(newValue))
{
    stringList.Add(newValue);
}
```

Note that if you're currently just concerned about the performance in the abstract, you should set appropriate goals to determine what is *fast enough*, and measure against those goals - while writing the simplest possible code. Do you know that the list will actually become large in your real application?

Answer (score 2):

```
List <string> lsLinks = new List<string>();
bool contains = lsLinks.Any(s => s.Equals("myString");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
 lsLinks.Contains(myString);
```

or

```
 lsLinks.Where(o=>o==myString);
```

But if your goal is to ensure unique strings, you can use a HashSet instead rather than a List,
  if the order of strings is unimportant.

Answer (score 2):

You could use HashSet instead of List<> if you don't care order of items. That collection has especially designed for best speed in comparison operations as it uses hashes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood what you wanted, but try this :

```
if(!lsLinks.Contains(NewString)) lsLinks.Add(NewString)
```